# Powershell script to get the list of users along with license(stakeholder,basic etc.) assigned to them in TFS

Tags: powershell, tfs

Hi I was looking for a powershell script or using rest api to get the list of users in TFS along with the license that is assigned to them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code to show? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you have something you tried and it failed or did research into it or any kind of attempt....then this is the place for you. If you want someone to write the whole thing for you then you should hire a developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use below PowerShell script which use the REST API to get the list of users along with license:

```
$stakeholderUrl = "http://server:8080/tfs/_api/_identity/ReadLicenseUsers?__v=5&licenseTypeId=242a857e-50ce-43d9-ba9f-3aa82457d726" # stakeholder           
$basicUrl = "http://server:8080/tfs/_api/_identity/ReadLicenseUsers?__v=5&licenseTypeId=8b71784c-27ab-4490-bb97-e699ed4123e1" # basic
$AdvancedUrl = "http://server:8080/tfs/_api/_identity/ReadLicenseUsers?__v=5&licenseTypeId=f29e17f1-60bd-44f0-ab2f-d67207ee9484" # Advanced

$stakeholder = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $stakeholderUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).identities 
$basic = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $basicUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).identities 
$Advanced = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AdvancedUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).identities


$StakeholderUsers = @()

foreach($user in $stakeholder){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "IdentityType" = "stakeholder"+":"+$user.IdentityType
          "DisplayName" = $user.DisplayName
          "SubHeader" = $user.SubHeader
          "AccountName" = $user.AccountName
        } 

    $StakeholderUsers += $customObject      
}

$StakeholderUsers | Select `
                IdentityType,
                DisplayName, 
                SubHeader,
                AccountName

$basicUsers = @()

foreach($user in $basic){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "IdentityType" = "basic"+":"+$user.IdentityType
          "DisplayName" = $user.DisplayName
          "SubHeader" = $user.SubHeader
          "AccountName" = $user.AccountName
        } 

    $basicUsers += $customObject        
}

$basicUsers | Select `
                IdentityType,
                DisplayName, 
                SubHeader,
                AccountName

$AdvancedUsers = @()

foreach($user in $Advanced){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "IdentityType" = "Advanced"+":"+$user.IdentityType
          "DisplayName" = $user.DisplayName
          "SubHeader" = $user.SubHeader
          "AccountName" = $user.AccountName
        } 

    $AdvancedUsers += $customObject     
}

$AdvancedUsers | Select `
                IdentityType,
                DisplayName, 
                SubHeader,
                AccountName
```

[image]

Comment: What is the licenseTypeId= for Enterprise users?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT- Can you please let me know the licenseType Id for VS Enterprise users? I need to get the details of Enterprise users as well.

Comment: @uttarabhosale VS Enterprise licenseTypeId=519a4528-2bd6-4ea4-b3cb-5440c1aaebc3

Comment: Thanks a million !!